# WebRTC - RTCPeerConnection.localDescription returns null in Firefox, but works correctly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I have built a simple streaming service using WebRTC. I'm currently still running everything through localhost. Everything currently works when using the Chrome browser, but I can not connect when I utilize Firefox. I am using the WebRTC-Adapter shim.

The problem seems to stem from peerConnection.localDescription always being equal to null, and being unable to send my localDescription to the peer, or set the remoteDescription correctly.

Here is a snippet of my code. This only covers the recipient of the stream, who is initiating the p2p connection. The streamer already has a local stream set up, and sets their own local and remote description, and the localDescription is then sent to the recipient. sendRecipientDescription() just handles sending the sdp to the streamer via sockets. PC_Config just includes a STUN server:

```
setUpRecipient = () => {
  this.createPeerConnection();
  this.pc
    .createOffer({ offerToReceiveVideo: true })
    .then(offer => {
      this.pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.sendRecipientDescription();
      console.log('recipient local description ', this.pc.localDescription);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('error recipient set up ', e);
    });
};

createPeerConnection = () => {
  try {
    this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(PC_CONFIG);
    this.pc.onicecandidate = this.handleIceCandidate;
    this.pc.ontrack = this.handleRemoteStreamAdded;
    this.pc.onremovetrack = this.handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
    this.pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = this.handleIceStateChange;
    console.log('Created RTCPeerConnection', this.pc.localDescription);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ', e.message);
  }
};
```

When using the Chrome browser, this.pc.localDescription returns as would be expected. When using the Firefox browser, this.pc.localDescription is always null, there is no RTCSessionDescription at all. When I console.log(this.pc) after setLocalDescription, it appears as though localDescription is indeed null: [RTCPeerConnection un-expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR5rY.png)

However, when I expand the RTCPeerConnection object, you see that localDescription appears to be set up correctly: [RTCPeerConnection expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3z01.png). But, when I try to send this.pc.localDescription, it only sends null.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer to my own question. Apparently I needed to return this.pc.setLocalDescription();

I don't know why this is necessary. As far as I know, pc.setLocalDescription does not return anything, and only has the side effect of setting pc.localDescription. It worked perfectly fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: `setLocalDescription` returns a promise. Without the return statement, the promise chain won't wait for the asynchronous operation to complete before continuing to `sendRecipientDescription`. You had a race condition that happened to work in Chrome but not in FF because the timing was different at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation noppa, I appreciate it.